# Why make argument listings so confusing?

Tags: php

I'm looking at PHP documentation for mail(). I understand how to read it, but I'm about to show it to a complete beginner, and I it made me reflect on how bad he formatting is.

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

First of all, I understand putting [] round optional parameters, but why enclose the second optional parameter in the square brackets for the first?

Secondly, why bother at all? The heading for each parameters tells you if it's optional.

Thirdly, for a language where type doesn't come up much, is giving the type of each argument in the main definition that helpful?

I'm most interested in the first point.

Imagine this in the context of me saying "Sending an email in PHP is really easy! Let's just Google it". Then we look at the documentation, and a learner who is already slightly confused by brackets and keywords is having to read and understand a whole other syntax of brackets and keywords.

I realise the docs are not learning material, but it seems to me they could be easier to read while remaining suitable for the expert. I notice other languages use this syntax too - are their good reasons I just haven't noticed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all, I understand putting [] round optional parameters, but why enclose the second optional parameter in the square brackets for the first?

I'm not 100% sure about the innards of PHP, but in statically typed languages that notation is because they're separate overloads of the function.  So when you're calling with one optional parameter you're actually calling a different function than with both optional parameters.

It also conveys that the optional parameters aren't linked in any way, that you can optionally include one or maybe the other (depending on the function definition) or both.  Sometimes a pair of optional parameters can be logically tied together such that if you include one you should include both, and they'd be grouped in brackets in this notation.

> Secondly, why bother at all? The heading for each parameters tells you if it's optional.

To convey this information in the function signature notation.  There's lots of information in the rest of the documentation, but required/optional is part of the signature itself and useful to include in that one brief notation.

> Thirdly, for a language where type doesn't come up much, is giving the type of each argument in the main definition that helpful?

So you know what it expects to receive.  Maybe this isn't a big deal where all of the function arguments are strings, but it can be important when they need to be something else.  You can pass a numeric as a string and it'll be fine, but if you pass a character string as a numeric it'll be less fine.  Or if you pass a string as a resource in the case of database queries for example.  PHP isn't statically typed, but data types are still important.

> I realise the docs are not learning material

Sure they are, as reference instead of tutorial.  Different format, same wealth of information.  Reference materials are always like this, though.  Dictionaries, encyclopedias, etc. all have their own notations that have been defined over the years to quickly convey structured information in headings before elaborating in unstructured descriptions.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very comprehensive answer. I think "function signature" is the term I needed to dig out more info on this.